# Adding a SQL column while also filling it in with a value from each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a column `LastUpdated` of type `DateTime`, and would like to add a column `LastUpdated2` to this table.  I would like to populate it with whatever `LastUpdated` is for each existing row in the table.

Eg:

| LastUpdated |
| --- |
| 12:01 PM |
| 5:00 PM |

Becomes:

| LastUpdated | LastUpdated2 |
| --- | --- |
| 12:01 PM | 12:01 PM |
| 5:00 PM | 5:00 PM |

Quite simply as you can see, I just want them to match.

I see a lot of example out there for an `ALTER` statement that has a default value, but didn't find any that have a specific value for each row as they're updated.

Optimally I'd want my code to be something like this, hopefully this pseudocode makes sense:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Appointments
    ADD LastUpdated2 DATETIME
        DEFAULT (SELECT LastUpdated FROM CurrentRow)
```

I've also considered maybe just doing an `ALTER` statement, and then an `UPDATE` statement. Maybe this is the only way how to do it?

Comment: But ***why*** would you want to store the same date&time *twice* in each row?!?!

Comment: This is really just an example question, but I get why you would say that.  In real application the second one will be getting changed a lot while first one needs to stay same.

Comment: No, you cannot do that, you need to alter the table then populate the data. How many times are you going to need to do this? Once, I should imagine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking there is no way to do this all within the ALTER statement by itself.  Needs to be two separate statements:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Appointments
ADD LastUpdated2 DATETIME

UPDATE dbo.Appointments
SET LastUpdated2 = LastUpdated
```

This accomplishes what I am trying to do I think.  I was curious if there was a way to do it inside of just the ALTER statement, but maybe not.  I don't see any examples online.

Comment: I have not seen an alternative - you may consider an alter column to add a not null constraint afterward populating the data (assuming that is your data constraint).

Answer (score 0):

You could add it as a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16), persisted if you want it to actually store the data to disk:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Appointments
ADD LastUpdated2 AS LastUpdated PERSISTED;
```

The caveat to doing this, is it will always be based off of the `LastUpdated` column, as it changes. If you need it to only match the `LastUpdated` column initially, then doing a two step process via `ALTER` then `UPDATE` like your answer is the way.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I've actually never used a computed column, so I learned something here.

Comment: @CheckpointSoftworks No problem, they're actually very handy for different scenarios with persisting transformed data. You're allowed to apply functions inside of them and then persist their results to disk, so said function is only calculated on initial `INSERT`. Feel free to upvoted me if you felt this answer was helpful, so others may see it verified as useful.

Comment: I can't upvote yet.

Comment: @CheckpointSoftworks No worries. You can also mark the answer as "accepted" for others to see it as verified too, if you should choose, but no obligation.